# Excel how to define connection on the current workbook

Tags: sql, excel, microsoft-query

**I'm trying to run SQL queries in Excel.**

The only option that allows me to do so is inserting data from an **external source with Microsoft Query**, selecting Excel Files as the data source and pointing **at the current workbook**.

Stupid as it is, it actually works, however it burns the path of the file into the connection that it defines in the workbook, meaning I can't move or redistribute the file.

The connection will have the following definition:

**connection string:**

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\Temp\Alma.xlsx;DefaultDir=C:\Temp;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;
```

**query:**

```
select e.bizszam, e.bevsor, e.afa, u.afa
from this.EredetiAdat e
inner join this.UjAdat u on e.bizszam = u.bizszam and e.bevsor = u.bevsor and e.afa <> u.afa
where e.afa NOT IN (select u2.afa from `C:\Temp\Alma.xlsx`.UjAdat u2 where u2.bizszam = u.bizszam and u2.bevsor = u.bevsor)
OR u.afa NOT IN (select e2.afa from `C:\Temp\Alma.xlsx`.EredetiAdat e2 where e2.bizszam = e.bizszam and e2.bevsor = e.bevsor)
```

As you can see there is a path (C:\Temp\Alma.xlsx) in both of the above. I want to get rid of that. **How can I make the connection point at the workbook itself, at the running instance, regardless of wherever it is??**

If there is any other way (native Excel, no plug-ins!) to run SQL queries on the tables of a workbook I'd also be happy with that. I've tried using MS Power Query but as far as I can tell it's completely useless.

Comment: P.S.: Yeah I know that query is stupid, believe me, the source data is as well...

Comment: One option might be to put the source data in a separate workbook and put it in an accessible location. Otherwise, you'll need to write some VBA to update the connection when the file is opened.

Comment: Sadly that wouldn't work, they just want to toss this Excel file around and use ad-hoc. Can't make a centralized datasource.
However the VBA idea sounds feasible, though I have no idea where to start. :/